# Developer error in Sign in with google with firebase in android studio

Tags: android, react-native, react-google-login

[Promise rejection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKpa2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKpa2.png)

I have tried clean project and rebuild project. This project is also run in ios device. I also add a SHA key in firebase console.